# Не равномерная балансировка терминальных серверов через haproxy Почему

Tags: балансировка

У меня настроенный haproxy для балансировки нагрузки на терминальные сервера.
На странице статистики можно видеть не равномерное распределение нагрузки на сервера при чистом запуске (1 раз грубо говоря). Пробовал разные типы баланса. Все одинаково. [image: статистика веб]
Пользователь с  йп 192.168.112.5 уже не может подключиться и почему его кидает на srv20 у него уже лимит maxconn, хотя есть много других свободных? Похоже я начинаю понимать в чем дело. У нас доменные пользователи в клиенте пишут имя как домен\имя а так как домен у на больше 9 символов то он обрезается и пользователь попадает на тот же сервер. Знатоки поправьте меня.
Вопрос как использовать правильно haproxy в этом случае.

```
 haproxy[27723]: 192.168.112.5:53798 front_rdp rdp_servers/srv20 1002/-1/+1001 +0 sQ 215/212/211/60/0 1/0
 haproxy[27723]: 192.168.129.2:54605 front_rdp rdp_servers/srv20 1003/-1/+1002 +0 sQ 215/214/213/60/0 1/0
```

Вот конфиг

```
global

log 127.0.0.1   local2
stats socket /tmp/haproxy.stats

        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon
        maxconn 10000

defaults
        mode tcp
        log global
        option logasap
        retries 2
        maxconn 10000
        timeout connect 5s
        timeout queue 1s
        timeout client 8h
        timeout server 8h


# Stat web
frontend stats
        mode http
        bind 192.168.0.242:8001         
        stats enable                    
        stats hide-version              
        stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics 
        stats uri /haproxy              
        stats auth stat:stat            
        stats refresh 10s               

###############################################

frontend front_rdp
        mode tcp
        bind 192.168.0.242:3389 name rdp
        option tcpka
        option tcplog
        tcp-request inspect-delay 3s
        tcp-request content accept if RDP_COOKIE
       persist rdp-cookie
        default_backend rdp_servers


backend rdp_servers
        mode tcp
       balance leastconn
#        balance roundrobin

        option tcp-check
        option tcpka
        stick-table type string len 32 size 100k expire 8h
        stick on rdp_cookie(mstshash)
        default-server inter 3s rise 2 fall 2 maxqueue 1

        server srv20 192.168.200.20:3390 maxconn 60 weight 50 check
        server srv21 192.168.200.21:3390 maxconn 65 weight 50 check
        server srv22 192.168.200.22:3390 maxconn 65 weight 50 check
        server srv23 192.168.200.23:3390 maxconn 60 weight 50 check
        server srv24 192.168.200.24:3390 maxconn 65 weight 50 check
        server srv25 192.168.200.25:3390 maxconn 65 weight 50 check
        server srv27 192.168.200.27:3390 maxconn 65 weight 50 check
        server srv28 192.168.200.28:3390 maxconn 65 weight 50 check
        server srv34 192.168.200.34:3390 maxconn 65 weight 50 check
```

Comment: А всякие persist и stick в конфиге вас не смущают?

Comment: Ваш вопрос мне понятен. Но это  1 чистая загрузка в таблице ничего нету. Вы имеете ввиду что запомнились куки и на кидает на тот же сервер?

Comment: Ну как бы смысл этих кук ровно в том что бы кидать на тот же сервер.

Comment: Да для терминалов это как раз нормально. Пусть юзер попадает на один сервер в течении 8 ч. Но что с неравномерной нагрузкой то. после рестарта

Comment: Сам отвечу на свою проблему. Да действительно. Клиенты РДП от мелкомягких отдают куки в которых имя только 9 символов. Поэтому решение такое. Писать в поле Пользователь имя@домен. Либо отказаться от рдп кук, что я и сделал. Использовать таблицу с ip  `stick-table type ip size 10k expire 8h
stick on src`